# How to add a timestamp as the last column of an existing Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was looking for the most Pythonic solution available, but didn't see it published anywhere to my liking, so am submitting this as a self-answered question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.insert(df.columns.size, 'createts', pd.to_datetime('now').replace(microsecond=0))
```